# Contrary meanings of dependency/dependent?

Tags: meaning

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html#whatis says that

> Whenever a class A uses another class or interface B, then A depends on B. A cannot carry out it's work without B, and A cannot be reused without also reusing B. In such a situation the class A is called the "dependent" and the class or interface B is called the "dependency". A dependent depends on its dependencies.

According to Google, the definition of "dependency":

> a dependent or subordinate thing, especially a country or province controlled by another.

Since A depends on B,  the dependency is  A and the dependent is B. This is contrary to the first quote. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If state (etc) X has sovereignty over state Y, Y is a dependency (a country or province controlled by another, {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dependency)} of X. But X may still be dependent on Y for its iron ore. You're 'missing' the different senses of the words; Jenkov seems to be using an IT-specific sense. And to have a poor proofreader.

Comment: I think you've made a good case that 'dependency' is an example of a [contronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym)

Comment: See also "[Single word for expressing "those which I am dependent on"](/q/284299/3107)", "[What is the word for the complementary relationship implied by the word dependent?](/q/573742/3107)".

Answer (score -1):

I think Jenkov says: dependant (A) depends on dependency (B).
The d**e**pendent thing is B, but A is the dependant.

Hope this helps.