# What do you call the opposite of dependent?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Say you have 3 things (eg tasks), A-C. A must be done before B, and B before C. One would say that B is dependent on A, and C is dependent on B.

What if you want to say the opposite, like A is a parent of B? Parent doesn't quite sound right, nor does child. The "true" opposite of dependent is independent, but that means unrelated however A is related to B, because B is dependent on A, so that doesn't fit either.

Thinking about it more, saying "A is a parent to B, and "B is a child to A" makes the most sense, but it feels off.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: _Independent_ doesn't necessarily mean _unrelated_, just _not dependent on_.

Comment: See also [Contrary meanings of dependency/dependent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416182/contrary-meanings-of-dependency-dependent) and [If "X is a dependency of Y" then "Y is a ??? of X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509649/if-x-is-a-dependency-of-y-then-y-is-a-of-x), among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Antecedent

The strict dictionary definition isn't quite an *exact* match, but in graph theory (at least withing a computing context), if B was dependent on A you'd say A was an **antecedent** of B:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-conductor/2.4.1?topic=instances-service-dependencies

> Services can have dependencies on other services. A service that other services depend on is called an **antecedent** service. If a service depends on the antecedent service, the **antecedent service must be running for the dependent service to work properly**.

And a dictionary definition for completeness:

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/antecedent

> something that happened or existed before something else and is similar to it in some way